# TS define type to equal one of values of typed array

Tags: typescript, types, typing

Lets assume I have an access to a type `Keys` that is defined like so:

```js
type Keys = ('AA' | 'BB' | 'CC')[]
```

1. How can I create a new type `Key`, using type `Keys`, so that this new type be equal to:

```js
type Key = 'AA' | 'BB' | 'CC'
```

Note that I cannot literally specify allowed values (`AA`, `BB`, etc), I only have `Keys` type available to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [indexed type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

```
type Keys = ('AA' | 'BB' | 'CC')[]
type Key = Keys[number]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oAoDkBBLGoB8oMAhYvQjAYUowEoBtAXQChRJZ4UPF6A7AVwC2AIwgAnRkA)